# Extract value from double callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, fs

**How can I assign value to variable in global from double callback?**

First of, I read some value from file, when its done, I pass it to some fn in callback and want to use result value in initial scope, outside callback.

I can't wrap my head around this for some reason although at first it looks trivial.

```
var done = function(err, value) {
    if (err) {
        return;
    }
    var resultValue = someMethod(value);
};


loadFile(done);

var resultVal = ?? //result value needed here

function loadFile(done) {
    fs.realpath(filePath, function (err, resolvedPath) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }

        fs.readFile(resolvedPath, function (err, value) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            return done(null, data);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you have remove 'var' in the done function ? resultValue = someMethod(value);

Comment: This isn't going to work because of the asynchronous nature of your call. You can set the global var `resultValue` but there will be no guarantee it will be available when you call it right after `loadFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment you are using an asynchronous call to load a file. You want the result of `someMethod` stored into the *global variable* `resultVal`. Except this isn't possible.

When you call `loadFile(done)` a asynchronous call is made to the server. This call is being resolved by an event. If the event returns `200` the server returned the expected answer. If their is an error it will be passed to `done`, if not the `data` will be passed. Let's say this takes about `250 ms` to resolve.

In the mean time JavaScript continued parsing the code, because the call was asynchronous, running in a separate thread, thus not halting the execution of the main thread. The next line that gets parsed is `returnVal`. However the call isn't resolved yet because this line gets executed `1 ms` after the function `loadFile` was called. This leaves a gap of `249 ms`.

The solution is to rethink your code to cope with the asynchronous call.

```
var done = function(err, value) {
    if (err) {
        return;
    }
    var resultValue = callBack(value);
};


loadFile(done);

function someMethod(value)
{
    //execute whatever you want to do here!
}

function loadFile(done) {
    fs.realpath(filePath, function (err, resolvedPath) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }

        fs.readFile(resolvedPath, function (err, value) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            return done(null, data);
        });
    });
}
```

Of course you can provide the function done with the callback you want. Just look at this code:

```
var done = function(err, value, callBack) {
    if (err) {
        return;
    }
    var resultValue = someMethod(value);
};


loadFile(done, method1);

function method1(value)
{
    //execute whatever you want to do here!
}

function loadFile(done, callBack) {
    fs.realpath(filePath, function (err, resolvedPath) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }

        fs.readFile(resolvedPath, function (err, value) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            return done(null, data, callBack);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring resultValue as : var resultValue = someMethod(value);
You can do global.resultValue = someMethod(value);
This will make resultValue as a global variable.
You can access it anywhere using global.resultValue.

Similarly,instead of using global you can also use process.
global and process are global objects for nodejs just like window is for javascript.